# Start an intent to start a specific tab of tab host

Tags: java, android

I'm developing this android app and the home view has three tabs. The notifications tab is not the default tab of the tab host. So in notifications I just coded for users to delete each notification, and what I want the app to do after delete a notification is to reload the the notifications. Now since I want to maintain the tab view I can't do this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Notification.class);

                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
```

because that would load the notifications in a full screen view out of the tab views but if I do

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TabExercise.class);

                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
```

I go to the default tab of the tab host and not notifications. So I was wondering if there was a way to send an intent to Tabexercise pointing to a specific tab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Send intent to `Tabexercise` along with the index of the tab as follows:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, TabExercise.class);
i.putExtra("tab_index","1");
startActivity(i);
```

inside `onCreate()` of  `Tabexercise` set the current tab by reading the parameter that you passed:

```
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost); //Assuming that you are setting your tabHost like this
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("tab_index");
    if(value.equals("1"){
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(Integer.valueOf(value)); 
    }
    //and so on ...

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the intent your are sending to `TabExercise`, you can send the tabindex you want to load, and then call [setCurrentTab (int index)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#setCurrentTab%28int%29). Did you try something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this on your starting intent

```
intent.putExtra("notificationsTab",true);
```

Then in your `onCreate` method in your activity which is hosting the tab, do a check to see if it is true.

```
int notificationsTab = 3;
if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("notificationsTab")) tabHost.setCurrentTab(notificationsTab);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intHome = new Intent().setClass(this, MainActivity.class);
    intHome.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
    TabSpec tabhome = tabHost
      .newTabSpec("Home")
      .setIndicator("Home", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.house))
      .setContent(intHome);


    Intent intfav = new Intent().setClass(this, Favourite.class);
    intfav.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
    intfav.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    TabSpec tabfav = tabHost
      .newTabSpec("Settings")
      .setIndicator("FAVOURITE", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.star))

      .setContent(intfav);

    Intent intinfo = new Intent().setClass(this, Information.class);
    TabSpec tabinfo = tabHost
      .newTabSpec("Settings")
      .setIndicator("INFO", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.about))
      .setContent(intinfo);

    tabHost.addTab(tabhome);
    tabHost.addTab(tabfav);
    tabHost.addTab(tabinfo);
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

and you are saying you want to reload activity so use can reload activity using onResume() or onPause() method int that particular activity.

Hope it will help you